# Laravel Elixir Gulp Version Error

Tags: laravel, gulp, version, laravel-elixir

It was fine before, after my computer got BSOD when doing gulp, now the gulp version. I have tried to remove node_modules and do npm install but the error still there, thanks.

```
D:\laravel>gulp
[09:30:55] Using gulpfile D:\laravel\gulpfile.js
[09:30:55] Starting 'all'...
[09:30:55] Starting 'styles'...
[09:30:55] Finished 'styles' after 323 ms
[09:30:55] Starting 'scripts'...
[09:30:55] Finished 'scripts' after 65 ms
[09:30:55] Starting 'version'...
[09:30:55] 'version' errored after 920 μs
[09:30:55] SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at VersionTask.deleteManifestFiles (D:\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\tasks\VersionTask.js:113:29)
at VersionTask.gulpTask (D:\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\tasks\VersionTask.js:71:18)
at VersionTask.run (D:\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\tasks\Task.js:138:31)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (D:\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\tasks\GulpBuilder.js:65:67)
at module.exports (D:\laravel\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\laravel\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\laravel\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (D:\laravel\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
at runNextSet (D:\laravel\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:86:16)
[09:30:55] 'all' errored after 395 ms
[09:30:55] SyntaxError in plugin 'run-sequence(version)'
Message:
Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
Stack:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at VersionTask.deleteManifestFiles (D:\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\tasks\VersionTask.js:113:29)
at VersionTask.gulpTask (D:\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\tasks\VersionTask.js:71:18)
at VersionTask.run (D:\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\tasks\Task.js:138:31)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (D:\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\dist\tasks\GulpBuilder.js:65:67)
at module.exports (D:\laravel\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\laravel\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\laravel\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (D:\laravel\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
at runNextSet (D:\laravel\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:86:16)
```

Comment: Please note that [tag:elixir] is a programming language, please be careful with tags. I have changed it to be [tag:laravel-elixir].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix this issue, just delete your `public/build` folder and then run gulp again. I faced this issue several times and everytime my issue is fixed by deleting the build folder.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Legend! I've spent 2hours on this. Deleting the build folder fixed the issue